# Cylinder is not being displayed on screen

Tags: qt, opengl, drawing, paint, glu

Well, what i'm trying to do is to draw a Cylinder using GLUquadricObj and gluCylinder, the code compiles fine whatever the Cylinder is not being displayed on the OpenGL widget.

```
void GLWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();

    gluCylinder(obj, 1.0, 1, 3, 30, 30);

    glEnd();
}
```

What's preventing the cylinder from being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it, was an issue with the resizeGL(). Doing glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); + glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); was causing this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a limited [number of things you can do inside a `glBegin()` block](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBegin.xml).  That list *does not* include [another `glBegin()`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glu/sgi/libutil/quad.c#n264).

Also, try a non-default view frustum.  I'd recommend [`gluPerspective()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

Comment: I've fixed it, was an issue with the resizeGL(). Doing glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); + glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); was causing this.

EDIT: it is also possible to give the cylinder no-top?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the proper initialization of opengl and of the scene in the initializeGL() function?

Comment: Yes, it's initialized.
`void GLWindow::initializeGL()
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }`